# Making facet with Donut Plots in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am working with R and Plotly. I face with one problem related with making facet plot with this library. Below you can see example of my data and my attempt to make facet with two Donut plot in Plotly.

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
# Get Manufacturer
mtcars$manuf <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(mtcars), " "), "[[", 1)
df <- mtcars
df <- df %>% group_by(manuf)
df <- df %>% summarize(count = n())

# Donut 1
fig <- df %>%
            plot_ly(labels = ~manuf, values = ~count) %>%
            add_pie(hole = 0.6) %>%
            layout(
              title = "Donut charts using Plotly 1",
              showlegend = TRUE,
              xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
              yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
              annotations = list(
                x = 0, y = -0.1,
                showarrow = FALSE,
                xref = 'paper',
                yref = 'paper',
                align = 'left'
              ))

# Donut 2
fig1 <- df %>%
            plot_ly(labels = ~manuf, values = ~count) %>%
            add_pie(hole = 0.6) %>%
            layout(
              title = "Donut charts using Plotly 2",
              showlegend = TRUE,
              xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
              yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
              annotations = list(
                x = 0, y = -0.1,
                showarrow = FALSE,
                xref = 'paper',
                yref = 'paper',
                align = 'left'
              ))
# Making Facet
facet_fig <- subplot(
  fig,
  fig1,
  nrows = 1,
  margin = 0.05
)

facet_fig
```

This code produce two Donut plots but problem is that, those plots can be putted on the same place with command **subplot** as is shown in the pic below.

[image]

Can anybody help me how to solve this problem and put two Donut plots in the same figure(facet plot) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not understand how your plot should look like. Could you please explain or uploaded an expected output that you wanted to look like.

Comment: @ManojKumar See pic above. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the issues is how and what data you try to plot: Here is an example of a counting by `am` and `manuf`:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

# data
mtcars$manuf <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(mtcars), " "), "[[", 1)
df <- mtcars %>% 
      group_by(am, manuf) %>% 
      summarize(count = n())

# Donut 1
fig1 <- plot_ly(df %>% 
                  count(am, manuf) %>% 
                  filter(am == 0), labels = ~manuf, values = ~n, type = 'pie', hole = 0.6,
                domain = list(x = c(0, 0.48), y = c(0, 1))) %>%
        layout(
          title = "Donut Chart 1 and 2",
          showlegend = FALSE,
          xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
          yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)
        )

# Donut 2
fig2 <- plot_ly(df %>% 
                  count(am, manuf) %>% 
                  filter(am == 1),
                  labels = ~manuf, values = ~n, type = 'pie', hole = 0.6,
                domain = list(x = c(0.52, 1), y = c(0, 1))) %>%
        layout(
          title = "Donut Chart 1 and 2",
          showlegend = TRUE,
          xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
          yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)
        )

facet_fig <- subplot(fig1, fig2, nrows = 1, shareX = TRUE, shareY = TRUE, titleX = FALSE, titleY = FALSE)
facet_fig
```

[image]

Comment: Any possibility to have different legend about two Donut plots and different titles above the Donut plots ?